# ASP.net / C# Parameter

Tags: asp.net

My code is not working. `@X` is my parameter ans ASP.NET shows error near `@X` parameter.

Please help.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT top @x * FROM tblname",cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x",DropDown1.SelectedItem.value);
SqlDataReader dr;
dr=cmd.executeReader();
DataList1.DataSource = dr;
DataList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: why down-vote? people are not showing interest in voting-up a question, but vote it down..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `SELECT` statement this way:

```
SELECT top (@x) * from tblname
```

I only includes the brackets around `@x` parameter

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: thanks......I have one more question "is there any way to show a gridview with repeat columns ?"

Comment: thanks @marc_s. I will remember this in future posting.